# file mover script not working exceptedly

Tags: regex

### Need help on reg expression to string match for 4 below file names

`9369.PCTYYYYMMDD.txt
9370.PCTYYYYMMDD.txt
9369.s369YYMMDDd-0008-pct.txt 
9370.s370YYMMDDd-0008-pct.txt`

I have worked out like this `^93(69|70).(s369|s370|pct).*\.txt$`

but this is matching with the below file names also; which it should not
`9369.s369YYMMDDd-0023-pct.txt`
`9370.s370YYMMDDd-0023-pct.txt`

please help me.
 Thanks in advance....

Comment: The "|s370" exists in this group, "(s369|s370|pct)" if you don't want it to match s370 take that part out. ^93(69|70).(s369|pct).*\.txt$ I would normally post that as an answer but I'm not sure if the question is complete.

Comment: It isn't clear why you want to match `9369.s369YYMMDDd-0008-pct.txt` but not `9369.s369YYMMDDd-0023-pct.txt`. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `s370` from the second capturing group and don't forget to turn on the case insensitive modifier `i`.

```
^93(69|70)\.(s369|pct).*?\.txt$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hN6tA6/3)